# In Android, can a StaticLayout with Spans be Align.CENTER'ed?

Tags: android, drawtext

I am trying to center `CharSequence`s with `Span`s using `StaticLayout`. Everything works fine when `textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT`.

[image: working with LEFT alignment]

However, if I set `textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER`, everything gets wonky.

[image: wonky with CENTER alignment]

It looks as if the spanned portions are stripped out, then the "centering calc" is done, then the text is rendered.

In my code, the alignment is changed via `doCenter`.

```
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        //:

        val doCenter = true
        val textWidPct = 0.90F
        dpToUse = 10
        val cs = clueDisplayText

        val xPos: Float
        if (doCenter) {
            xPos = clueTextRect.exactCenterX()
            textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        } else {
            xPos = clueTextRect.width() * ((1 - textWidPct) / 2)
            textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
        }
        textPaint.typeface = k.typefaceNormal
        textPaint.textSize = j.dpToPx(dpToUse).toFloat()
        textPaint.color = cc.Black

        val wid = (width * textWidPct).round()
        val staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder
            .obtain(cs, 0, cs.length, textPaint, wid)
            .build()

        val yPos = clueTextY + j.dpToPx(dpToUse)
        canvas.withTranslation(xPos, yPos) {
            staticLayout.draw(canvas)
        }
    }
```

One final point:

Changing

```
            canvas.withTranslation(xPos, yPos) {
                staticLayout.draw(canvas)
            }
```

to simply

```
            staticLayout.draw(canvas)
```

moves the output to the upper left, but it's just as wonky.

I've researched this and cannot find anything on point. Not here at SO, nor elsewhere on the web. I did find a couple of things talking about this same type of issue with CSS where the conclusion seemed to be "can't be done".

Am I missing something simple here? Or is there a more complex approach I need to take? Or is this not possible?

note: minSdk is 23 (M / Marshmallow)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. Decided to post for anyone who may encounter this issue.

Don't use

```
    textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
```

set the alignment in the `StaticLayout.Builder`

```
    val staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder
        .obtain(cs, 0, cs.length, textPaint, wid)
        .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)
        .build()
```